# Trigger a function (not an alert) on tab close JavaScript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, tabs

**Details**
I am making a video calling page, and I want to remove the persons name from the list when he close the tab (close window/when refresh tab). So to remove the person, I want to trigger function `removePerson(me) //don't care the prop "me";`.  Is it possible?

**What i have tried**

 I tried using `onbeforunload`, `onunload` . But i couldn't achieve it;

**Please** help me to achieve it, no problem if it is with `onbeforunload`/ `onunload`.

Thanks, Rob Wilson

Comment: Surely you detect a user leaving at the server end, you shouldn't need the client to send a message to say it's leaving..

Comment: You can do it, but it is a race condition if it is an asynchronous call.

Comment: @Keith, is there any way to do it client-side?

Comment: You need this change to show for other people other than the one that just left the room ? In this case I don't think it can be done client-side. You need to update the list of participants in the server and propagate the change to the rest of clients

Comment: Oh! letme get into that, ty